# How do we concat a string in a View file in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, asp.net-mvc-5, app-config, concatenation

I am trying to concat a string in a view file for MVC.

How do we do that?

I am trying to use an application key value as the value:

```
<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleMapKey"].ToString() %>
```

I would like for it to go where the value of the Key is at:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6P8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxhNMwLG0M&sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the aspx view engine you could use this:

```
<% string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleMapKey"].ToString(); %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= key %>&sensor=false"></script>
```

and if you are using the Razor view engine then:

```
@{ string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleMapKey"].ToString(); }
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=@key&sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={0}&sensor=false",ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleMapKey"].ToString()) %>">
```

You are in fact using "string.Format" command which by the way, I believe is one of the most beneficial command in .Net.